# in ggplot2 , how to automatically calculate values for 'ylim'

Tags: r, ggplot2

in R ggplot2 ,I want to automatically calculate values for 'ylim' , but the error pop as below
"Error in limits(c(...), "y") : object 'sales' not found". Anyone can help ? thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_data <- data.frame(category=rep(letters[1:5],10),
                        amount=rep(rnorm(5),10))

plot_data %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(sales=sum(amount)) %>% 
  arrange(-sales) %>% mutate(category=fct_inorder(category))%>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=category,y=sales))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+ylim(min(sales)*1.1,max(sales)*1.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute the dataframe to `ggplot` by a dot `.` using `{}` around `ggplot` commands:

```r
plot_data %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(sales=sum(amount)) %>% 
    arrange(-sales) %>% mutate(category=fct_inorder(category))%>% 
    {ggplot(.,aes(x=category,y=sales))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity')+ylim(min(.$sales)*1.1,max(.$sales)*1.1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply split up the pipe, so it's possible to use the min/max values you receive after summarizing:

```
df1 <- plot_data %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(sales=sum(amount)) 

df1 %>% 
  arrange(-sales) %>% mutate(category=fct_inorder(category))%>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=category,y=sales))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+ylim(min(df1$sales)*1.1,max(df1$sales)*1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sales`, `plot_data$sales` will solve the problem